# gwt - how can i trigger clickEvent on FileUpload widget?

Tags: gwt, file-upload

I' m trying to create a simple Button and when it's clicked I want to trigger a hidden FileUpload widget which is inside a FormPanel. What I have done until now is two things:

1. I have created a native javascript
   function that clicks the FileUpload
   widget's element    when simple
   button is clicked.    This works
   fine in Firefox but it doesn't work
   in Chrome.
2. Also, I have created
   this: NativeEvent nevent =
   Document.get().createFocusEvent();//I have tried and createclickEvent() too.
   DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(nevent, fileUploadWidget);    This doesn't
   work at all.

Can anyone help me please??? I have searched a lot but I find nothing working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
myFileUpload.getElement().<InputElement>cast().click()
```

is what you're looking for.

For it to work in WebKit-based browsers (Chrome, Safari), the FileUpload has to be "moved out of view" but not hidden (as in `setVisible(false)`, which sets the CSS `display` property to `none`), i.e. something like (in CSS): `position:absolute; top: -1000px; left: -1000px;`

Answer (score 2):

*I believe* Thomas Broyer's answer is out of date now. I have just successfully used `myFileUpload.click()` with no problems.

I also used `setVisible(false)` on the the `FileUpload` field and it works in Chrome. Haven't tested in Safari but it would seem those issues have been resolved now.

Comment: I've been using SDM for ages and it works fine in Chrome and FF

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JSNI like this:

```
private native void triggerClick(Element e) /*-{
    e.click();
}-*/;
```

Then call

```
triggerClick(fileInput.getElement());
```