# GWT Programmatically Click FileUpload

Tags: java, gwt

Firstly, my development environment is Chrome/Safari with Eclipse Luna and Super Dev Mode on OSX Yosemite.

I am having a bit of a time with this widget. I have created a number of upload widgets (image, audio, video etc) which extend a base upload widget. The image upload calls FileUpload.click() upon initialisation and this works as expected in the the file dialog is shown. However, for the audio and video uploads, I need the user to select an option from a SuggestBox and then once a selection is made, FileUpload.click() should be fired (I already have the event handler in place etc). This last bit is not working, or doesn't appear to be as I do not get the file dialog being shown. I have traced the code execution in SuperDevMode and FileUpload.click() does appear to get fired (execution moves past this point and no error/exception is thrown), but I cannot, for the life of me get the dialog to be shown. The FileUpload element is not hidden/disabled (it used to be 'off screen', but I changed this just to be sure that that wasn't the issue).

What might be causing this - could it be an OS/browser issue, rather than a GWT one?

**UPDATE**

I decided to add a ClickHandler to the FileUpload widget which simply writes to the console when fired. Through both mechanisms the upload widget is 'clicked', so I really am at a loss of where to go next. Interestingly, if I remove the SuggestBox from the audio upload and just call the click function, I do get the popup, but I don't see why this should interfere with click if present.

---

### Solved

Solved it. So it seems that trying to trigger a FileUpload click programmatically only currently works if the event triggering it is a ClickEvent. To solve this I have had to create my own native click event and fire that when the user makes a selection from the SuggestBox. Is this intended behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the click of a FileUpload like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5877219/1055664):

```
FileUpload f = new FileUpload(); 
f.getElement().<InputElement>cast().click();
```

For it to work in WebKit-based browsers (Chrome, Safari), the FileUpload has to be "moved out of view" but not hidden (as in setVisible(false), which sets the CSS display property to none), i.e. something like (in CSS): position:absolute; top: -1000px; left: -1000px;

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to reply. I have tried everything I can think of (which includes the above) and I cannot get it to work. If I trigger the click upload the initialisation of my widget, then it works. However, trying to trigger the click after some user event (in my case a SearchBox select event) results in no file dialog being shown. I don't understand why it works the first way, but not the second. As I said, I have traced through the code using SDM and everything is called/executed as I would expect.